# Background location tracking not working - Expo - Android

Tags: android, react-native, geolocation, location, expo

I am working on something where I need to track background location if the app is in background and also if the device is asleep. I currently have it working for app in background but it stops tracking when the device is asleep. I am using Expo for the app and using Expo Task Manager alongside Expo Location to fetch location in background.
Anyone have any idea how to fetch location while app is in background and device is in sleep mode ?

Here's the code

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => await _askForLocationPermission())();
  });

  this.backgroundLocationFetch = async () => {
    const { status } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === 'granted') {
      console.log('cmon dance with me!')
      await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('FetchLocationInBackground', {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
        timeInterval: 3000,
        distanceInterval: 1,
        foregroundService: {
          notificationTitle: 'Live Tracker',
          notificationBody: 'Live Tracker is on.'
        }
      });
    }
  }



  const _askForLocationPermission = async () => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setgpsErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
      }
    })();
  };


  return(
    <View>
      <Text></Text>
    </View>
  )
};

TaskManager.defineTask('FetchLocationInBackground', ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error bg", error)
    return;
  }
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    console.log("BGGGG->", locations[0].coords.latitude, locations[0].coords.longitude);
  }
});




export default App;
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: @FrancescoClementi I added the code

Comment: What SDK version of expo are you using? I think in 40+ this would not be valid anymore for requesting permissions?

Answer (score 1):

I want to share an observation about background location tracking using expo-location on Android devices. When running an app in development mode through the Expo Go app, background location tracking may not work as expected. This issue could be related to complications arising from the foreground service running within the Expo Go app instead of the standalone app.

However, when you create and install your app's APK (or the AAB), background location tracking with expo-location works correctly on Android devices.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had precisely the same problem and solved this by using and EventEmitter to dispatch the location updates to the UI component.

Top of file:

```
import EventEmitter from 'EventEmitter'

const locationEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

didMount:

```
locationEmitter.on(LOCATION_UPDATE, (locationData) => {
    console.log('locationEmitter locationUpdate fired! locationData: ', locationData);
    let coordinatesAmount = locationData.newRouteCoordinates.length - 1;
    this.setState({
        latitude: locationData.newRouteCoordinates[coordinatesAmount - 1].latitude,
        longitude: locationData.newRouteCoordinates[coordinatesAmount - 1].longitude,
        routeCoordinates: this.state.routeCoordinates.concat(locationData.newRouteCoordinates)
    })
})
```

componentWillUnmount:

```
locationEmitter.off(LOCATION_UPDATE);
```

inside background task definition:

```
locationEmitter.emit(LOCATION_UPDATE, locationData)
```

This succesfully sends the location data from the background task, but I'm still stuck in the problem of how to make the background task send location update batches more often. My related post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68441957/react-native-expo-location-how-to-make-the-background-location-service-update-m).

Comment: What EventEmitter library are you using? I see lots of people use fbemitter. In SDK40 I had to create a custom emitter that inherits from NativeEventEmitter in react-native. That seems to work fine.

Comment: I installed the EventEmitter library with the command "npm install EventEmitter" and imported it as in the code snippet above.

This seems to be some sort of a parent name for several libraries, because in my node_modules folder I can find "event-emitter", "eventemitter3" and "EventEmitter".

Anyway, it does its job, which is the main thing! :-)