# React Native background location (@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation) - problem installing, how to link modules with Expo managed workflow?

Tags: react-native, geolocation, expo

I'm developing a sports app with React Native / Expo which needs to track user background when the app is in the background.

This is related to my previous question ([React Native expo-location: How to make the background location service update more often?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68441957/react-native-expo-location-how-to-make-the-background-location-service-update-m)). I came to the conclusion that the background location tracking in the 'expo-location' package does not seem to sufficiently work, so I started building a new solution based on the package '@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation' (https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation) which I found was recommended in several tutorials.

So I installed the module and built my map component based on the example code provided in the documentation (https://github.com/mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation#quick-example).

However, when running the app on Expo Go, I get the following error message despite doing all the required imports:

```
Component Exception: RNBackgroundGeolocation is undefined
```

This appears to be caused by a problem in linking modules, which I failed to do during the installation. The component requires to do linking of modules with the following command:

```
node ./node_modules/@mauron85/react-native-background-geolocation/scripts/postlink.js
```

Because I use Expo managed workflow, I lack the folder structure (./android/settings.gradle etc) required by this script and receive an error of 'android/settings.gradle not found'. Based on some searching, this seems to require running 'expo eject' on the whole project so that I can do configurations in the platform-specific folders.

However, 'expo eject' runs into errors in the "Installing JavaScript dependencies" phase and just returns an error of "Something went wrong ... ...", and the error logs provide no further clarification.

Questions:

1. How to get forward when something goes wrong in the 'expo eject' phase like this? The error logs get really messy and unclear.
2. I would really prefer to stay in the managed workflow to avoid any mess. Is there a way to get the modules linking work within the Expo managed workflow?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution